# Magento: Attribute with thousands of values/options

Tags: object, attributes, magento

I'm creating a Book store in Magento and am having trouble figuring out the best way to handle the Authors of a Book (which would be the product).

What I currently have is an Attribute called "authors" which is multi-select and a thousand [test] values. It's still manageable but does get a little slow when editing a product. Also, when adding an option/value to the authors attribute itself, a huge list is rendered in the HTML making this an inefficient solution.

- Is there another approach I should take?
- Is it possible to create an Author object (entity type?) which is associated to a product through a join table? If yes, can someone give me an explanation about how that is done or point me to some good documentation?
- If I'd take the Author object approach, could that still be used in the layered navigation?
- How would I show the list of all books for a single author?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I am aware of extensions like Improved Navigation but AFAIK it adds something like attributes to attributes themselves which is not what I'm looking for.

For Googlers: The same would apply for Artists of a music site or manufacturers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an author entity type, you'll just increase your work trying to add it to layered navigation, and I don't see a reason why it would be faster.

Your approach seems the best fit to the problem, given the way Magento is set up. How are you going to display 1,000 (which presumably pales in comparison to the actual list) authors in layered navigation?

Depending on the requirements, you could go the route of denormalizing the field and accepting text for it. That would still allow you to display it, search based on it, etc, but would eliminate the need to render every possible artist to manipulate the list. You could add a little code around selecting the proper artist (basically add an AJAX autocomplete to the backend field) to minimize typos as well.

Alternatively, you could write a simple utility to add a new artist to the system without some of the overhead of Magento's loading the list. To be honest, though, it seems that the lag that this has the potential to create on the frontend will probably outweigh the backend trouble.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Even with a thousand authors total it is possible a category/genre will only have a few common authors. The layered navigation for a specialist topic might not be that bad.

Comment: That's possible, but I wouldn't discount the "long tail" effect either, which will actually become even less efficient as the list of alphabetical. Usually, listing "top authors" is a good proxy for having a complete list of authors in a section.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers. I'm glad that I'm on the right track. However, I added some more test data to check how long it takes to save a product (during mass import): with 10 Attribute values it takes 2 seconds to save a product, with 5000 values it takes 3-4 seconds, with 10000 values it takes 5 seconds, with 20000 values it takes about 8-9 seconds. So, it does start to mess with my performance... Any recommendation to tackle this performance issue if I continue with the Attribute-based approach?

Comment: Either make the select-based approach faster (by strategically indexing, but I don't see this yielding results), or by moving away from select boxes. See above about text attributes.